# How to fetch only genuine contacts from iPhone in your app?

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8, contacts, xcode6.3.1

I need to fetch the contacts of iPhone in my app and I have written code for that. In some of the iPhones, few contacts are not genuine, I mean name is save as blank or by any random string like "6.w S" and in some number is not genuine. I want to fetch the contacts which are not like as shown in the image below  as it is crashing my app. So what checks I need to put in order to avoid fetching contacts like that. I am using Swift and my code is also written below:

**My Code:**

```
var people = ABAddressBookCopyArrayOfAllPeopleInSourceWithSortOrdering(self.objAddressBook, nil, ABPersonGetSortOrdering()).takeUnretainedValue() as NSArray  as [ABRecord]

        for person in people
        {
            var multiPhones:ABMultiValueRef = ABRecordCopyValue(person, kABPersonPhoneProperty).takeRetainedValue()

            for phoneNumbers in 0..<ABMultiValueGetCount(multiPhones)
            {
                var phoneNumber = ABMultiValueCopyValueAtIndex(multiPhones, phoneNumbers).takeRetainedValue() as! String

                var nameOfPerson: String = (ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue() as! String)

                var personRecordDic = ["name":nameOfPerson,"phone":phoneNumber]

                self.contactsArray.addObject(personRecordDic)
            }
        }
```

**Issue Causing Contactss**

[image]

Comment: Which lines are crashing and what is the exception? You probably need to only create a dictionary and add to the array if you have both a name and a phone number - at the moment you're assuming all contacts have both. Bad contacts data will always be an issue.

Comment: You can see there are two contacts with "No Name". They don't have contacts numbers also but still present in the Contacts and this causing crash.

Comment: ---------------var nameOfPerson: String = (ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue() as! String)----------------
This line causing the crash for "No Name" contacts and error is -------------------fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value-------------

Comment: Edit your question, don't put code in comments. And read the error message - it tells you exactly what is wrong

Comment: @ jrturton I understand the cause of crash but I DON"T WANT to fetch contacts which don't have enough information. And do you have any answer of this question?

Comment: Address book doesn't work like that. To perform a custom search, you get the array, (which you're already doing) then filter it (which you are not). @NileshPatel's answer is the correct approach.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78767/discussion-between-developer-and-jrturton).

Answer (score 0):

While fetching the contact add validation to your required fields.

Eg. If you are using Number,Email of contact then check wether those field have blank value or not. If blank value will be there then don't add to your list.

Comment: Error is about nil not blank ------fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value----
And can you please let me know how to check if value is nil in the following statement?------var nameOfPerson: String = (ABRecordCopyCompositeName(person).takeRetainedValue() as! String)----?

Comment: User optional chaining.. Use ? instead of ! because Optional chaining handle nil gracefully.. Let me know if you need anymore clarification.